# Trying to produce variable length horizontal lines based on variable numbers of candles in Pine

Tags: pine-script

After hours of working with arrays and loops hoping that would solve my problem I'm completely stumped on how to go about what I want with `pine` and yet what I want seems like it should be almost trivial so I'm hoping someone with pine experience can help.

The code attached has two approaches, one with arrays and one without but neither could I figure out how to do what I want so they only get so far, so, if you think you are seeing duplicate functionality, you are, obviously that has to be cleaned up once I have a path forward.

What I am trying to do is plot a line showing the highest point and lowest point of the candles for the length of candles where `isSideways` remains true and then not plot anything when `isSideways` is false. In other words just two straight horizontal lines in the shaded areas. Once that's figured out I'll want to draw lines a percentage of the way between those lines but that shouldn't be an issue once the first two lines are drawn.

It is trivial to draw a path that follows the candles, also to draw a horizontal line however to draw a horizontal line segment that fits in a limited but variable length range that's based on the highest or lowest values of those variable number of candles, that's proving to be considerably more difficult than I thought would be the case.

I'm using `barssince()` which gets me part way there but not all the way.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
//@version=4
study("Sideways Channel Visual", max_bars_back=4999)

sidewaysBbSource      = input(close, "SMA Source"              , type=input.source  ,                                        group="Sideways Detection")
sidewaysBbLength      = input( 50  , "SMA Length"              , type=input.integer , minval=1      ,                        group="Sideways Detection")
sidewaysBbrLen        = input( 21  , "Std Dev Signal Smoothing", type=input.integer , minval=1      , maxval=50,             group="Sideways Detection")
sidewaysBbMult        = input(  4.0, "Std Dev"                 , type=input.float   , minval=0.001  , maxval=50, step=0.001, group="Sideways Detection")
sidewaysBbrStdThresh  = input( 0.08, "Std Dev threshold"       , type=input.float   ,                            step=0.01 , group="Sideways Detection")

// Sideways indicator
sidewaysBasis   = sma(sidewaysBbSource, sidewaysBbLength)
sidewaysStdDev2 = sidewaysBbMult * stdev(sidewaysBbSource, sidewaysBbLength)
sidewaysUpper   = sidewaysBasis + sidewaysStdDev2
sidewaysLower   = sidewaysBasis - sidewaysStdDev2
sidewaysBbr     = (sidewaysBbSource - sidewaysLower)/(sidewaysUpper - sidewaysLower)
sidewaysStdDev  = stdev(sidewaysBbr, sidewaysBbrLen)
isSideways      = (sidewaysBbr > 0.0 and sidewaysBbr < 1.0) and sidewaysStdDev <= sidewaysBbrStdThresh

barsSinceNotSideways = barssince(not isSideways)
if barsSinceNotSideways == 0
    barsSinceNotSideways := 1 // highest/lowest will fail on 0.

hLevel = array.new_float(1, highest(high, barsSinceNotSideways))
lLevel = array.new_float(1, lowest (low , barsSinceNotSideways))

hNextLevel() =>
    _newLevel = isSideways ? array.get(hLevel, 0) : na
    array.set(hLevel, 0, _newLevel)
    _newLevel

lNextLevel() =>
    _newLevel = isSideways ? array.get(lLevel, 0) : na
    array.set(lLevel, 0, _newLevel)
    _newLevel

L  = lowest(high, barsSinceNotSideways)
H  = highest(low, barsSinceNotSideways)
LB = lowestbars(high, barsSinceNotSideways)
HB = highestbars(low, barsSinceNotSideways)

if not isSideways
    L := na
    H := na
    LB := na
    HB := na
    L
    H
    LB
    HB

bgcolor(title="Sidways", color=isSideways ? color.rgb(236, 64, 122, 90) : color.new(color.white, 100))

plot(hNextLevel(), title="Level High", color=color.red               , style=plot.style_cross, display=display.none)
plot(lNextLevel(), title="Level Low" , color=color.blue              , style=plot.style_cross, display=display.none)
plot(H           , "highest"         , color=color.new(color.red , 0), style=plot.style_cross, display=display.none)
plot(L           , "Lowest"          , color=color.new(color.blue, 0), style=plot.style_cross, display=display.none)
plot(HB          , "highest Bars"    , color=color.new(color.red , 0), style=plot.style_cross, display=display.none)
plot(LB          , "Lowest Bars"     , color=color.new(color.blue, 0), style=plot.style_cross, display=display.none)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found (just by chance I was looking for something else) an indicator that does this called `gaps&wicks` for anyone else who comes across this problem.